# Babel: transform wildcard exports?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Say that we have one file `base.js`:

```
export something from './something';
export somethingElse from './somethingElse'
```

and then a file `top.js`:

```
export * from './other/base'
```

Is it possible for Babel to turn the wildcard export in `top` into an explicit, flat export based on `base.js`?  E.g. the result should be something like:

```
export something from './other/something';
export somethingElse from './other/somethingElse'
```

Comment: They mean 2 different things, so I doubt they would be.   Also not even sure `export something from` is valid, did you mean -> `export {somethingElse} from "..`